# Pullback connection and diffeomorphism of the base

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, connections, pullback

Let $p \colon E \to B$ be a vector bundle, $\nabla^E \colon E \to E \otimes \Omega^1_B$ a connection on $E$, and $\phi \colon B \xrightarrow{\sim} B$ a diffeomorphism. Further, let there be a natural (fixed) isomorphism of vector bundles $\alpha \colon \phi^*(E) \to E$, for example because each fiber $p^{-1}(b)$ is naturally isomorphic to $p^{-1}(\phi(b))$. We can consider the pullback connection $\nabla^{\phi^*(E)} \colon \phi^*E \to \phi^*E \otimes \Omega^1_B$, defined by $$\nabla^{\phi^*E}(\phi^*f) = \phi^*(\nabla^E f) \cdot D(\phi).$$ In addition, $\alpha$ allows us to view sections of $E$ as sections of $\phi^*E$ and vice versa.

My question is, how does one compare the quantities $\nabla^{\phi^*E}(\phi^*f)$ and $\nabla^{\phi^*E}(\alpha^{-1} f)$? Or equivalently, how would you compare $\nabla^E(f)$ and $\nabla^E(\alpha(\phi^*(f)))$? How much does it depend on the nature of $\alpha$, and does it help if $D(\alpha)$ is identically $1$?

Comment: alpha can be given in awfully many different ways. In particular you can multiply by any nowhere zero regular function on B and still get an isomorphism of vector bundles. Then the nabla of alpha of pullback of f captures an extra factor by Leibnize rule. So unless there is further condition nothing much can be said about it.

Comment: In my situation, B is a PEL moduli problem, so that points correspond to Abelian varieties with extra structure. $\phi(b)$ corresponds to the same Abelian variety $A_b$ that $b$ does, and the fibers $p^{-1}(b)$ are a tensor power of $\Omega^1_{A_b}$, so that they can be naturally identified by $\alpha$ sending a differential to the same differential. Does this help anything? Or is there still too much wiggle room?

Comment: In your setting with $\nabla$ being the Gauss-Manin connection (I guess $\phi$ is something that has to do with endomorphism of abvar) every given geometric structure should be compatible with $\phi$ so they should be the same?